# Primera vez uso React no me carga en el navegardor la página No sale error a priori

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css3, react-navigation

Es la primera vez que so React.
No me sale ningún error, pero no consigo que me muestre por el navegador el título de la página

He revisado que el archivo index.css esté bien importado, así como las páginas que estoy creando y no veo ningún error

No se me ocurre que más mirar.
¿Alguien podría iluminarme?

Aunque parezca tonto lo digo, en el navegador pongo "http://localhost:3000/login"

Después de los asteriscos he puesto lo que he visto, que no me había dado cuenta antes, en la consola del navegador me pone esto:
Pero no sé a qué elemento me falta se refiere

Muestro código

Lo que muestra React después de compilar

`````
You can now view chat-front in the browser.      

  Local:            http://localhost:3000        
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.0.13:3000     

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build. 

assets by chunk 1.53 MiB (name: main)
  asset static/js/bundle.js 1.52 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
  asset main.04088a5f6ec7ef181c54.hot-update.js 2.84 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [hmr] (name: main) 1 related asset
assets by path *.json 343 bytes
  asset asset-manifest.json 315 bytes [emitted]
  asset main.04088a5f6ec7ef181c54.hot-update.json 28 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]
asset index.html 1.67 KiB [emitted]
Entrypoint main 1.53 MiB (1.56 MiB) = static/js/bundle.js 1.52 MiB main.04088a5f6ec7ef181c54.hot-update.js 2.84 KiB 2 auxiliary assets
cached modules 1.41 MiB [cached] 106 modules
runtime modules 28.2 KiB 13 modules
./src/index.js 1.47 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.65.0 compiled successfully in 198 ms````

index.js
```import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ChatApp from "./ChatApp";
import "./styles/index.css";

ReactDOM.render(<ChatApp />, document.getElementById("root"));```

app.jsx

```import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import LoginPage from "./Pages/LoginPage";
import RegisterPage from "./Pages/RegisterPage";
import DashboardPage from "./Pages/DashboardPage";

function ChatApp() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
        <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardPage} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default ChatApp;```

loginPage.jsx

```import React from "react";
// import makeToast from "../Toaster";
// import axios from "axios";
//import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const LoginPage = () => {
  return <div>Login Page</div>;
};

export default LoginPage;```
*********
````index.tsx:25 Matched leaf route at location "/login" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.````
`````

Answer (score 2):

Que versión de react-router-dom estas utilizando ? Supongo que lo has instalado no? Si tienes la versión 6, en vez de component debes poner element

Tal que así.

```
 <Route path="/login" element={LoginPage} />
```

Es la nueva forma de ponerlo el elemento.

Comment: Sí, es la versión 6,. También he probado con elemment y nada.

Comment: Gracias por tu aclaración me ayudó a solucionarlo